# MVC 4 multi routes in route.config

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, routes

I am using default route as

```
  routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{cvg}/{AgencyID}/{AgentCode}",
                defaults: new { AgentCode = UrlParameter.Optional, controller = "Login", action = "Index", cvg = UrlParameter.Optional, AgencyID = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

I need to set one route with only Agentcode. I have use as below. but failed to get result.

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{cvg}/{AgencyID}/{AgentCode}",
                defaults: new { AgentCode = UrlParameter.Optional, controller = "Login", action = "Index", cvg = UrlParameter.Optional, AgencyID = UrlParameter.Optional }
                );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Agency",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{AgentCode}",
                defaults: new { AgentCode = UrlParameter.Optional, controller = "Login", action = "Index" }
                );
        }
```

Am I missing some?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find my answer self as

"Make sure the Default route is at the BOTTOM of your listed route table. Order matters when it comes to ASP.NET MVC Routing tables.
The correct ordering is your 'most specific' route to your least specific route."

Comment: what about for webapi? does it matter?